# Angular Drag and Drop - Cannot Identify Current and Previous Container

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop

Angular 12

I am developing an interactive Task diagram, part of which will allow users to drag a padlock icon from one Task to another. On dropping the padlock I want to call a function which will edit some properties on the 'dragged from' Task and the 'dropped into' Task. The fundemental list is as follows: `*ngFor="let taskData of tasks; let i = index"`

Each Task is a component which includes a child padlock component. The dragged padlock uses `cdkDragData` to pass the parent Task's data into the drag operation.

For this feature to work I simply want to obtain the taskData from Task the padlock was dragged from and the taskData for the Task it was dropped into. Alternatively, the `currentindex` and `previousIndex` in the data array would suffice.

The Tasks are not displayed as a conventional list, the `taskData` passed to each Task includes a `locationX` and `locationY` property which determines the absolute position of each Task relative to the parent.

I have a simplified StackBlitz example here: [Angular Drag Drop](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-12-starter-project-daidh-4hfztw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

When I drag the padlock between Tasks, the `(cdkDropListDropped)="onDropPadlock($event)` event passed into the `onDropPadlock` function identifies the `currentIndex` and `previousIndex` as being the same. I cannot seem to obtain the correct `currentIndex` and `previousIndex` or the `data` object for both the 'dragged from' Task and the 'dropped into' Task.

Any suggestions or thoughts would be greatly appreciated.